# Exception: Stack is empty when using context.Forward() and AuthBot?

Tags: .net, azure, authentication, exception, botframework

I am following the SampleAADv2Bot example  from the AuthBot tutorial. I want to authenticate my bot using an Azure Active Directory that is already configured. I set up my Web.Config with what is pictured below. I have the same code in my dialog class as listed [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDX/AuthBot/blob/master/SampleAADv2Bot/Dialogs/ActionDialog.cs) except my class' name is LoginDialog.cs. I see this exception in the emulator however:

[image]

The error happens when I make this call in my code (in LoginDialog.cs):

```
 await context.Forward(new AzureAuthDialog(AuthSettings.Scopes), this.ResumeAfterAuth, message, CancellationToken.None);
```

Here is my LoginDialog Class. ResumeAfterAuth() is implemented.

LoginDialog.cs:

```
// Copyright (c) Microsoft. All rights reserved. Licensed under the MIT 
license. See full license at the bottom of this file.
namespace Bot.Dialogs
{
    using System;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using AuthBot;
    using AuthBot.Dialogs;
    using AuthBot.Models;
    using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs;
    using Microsoft.Bot.Connector;

    [Serializable]
    public class LoginDialog : IDialog<string>
    {
        public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
        {
            context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
        }

        public async Task TokenSample(IDialogContext context)
        {
            //endpoint v2
            var accessToken = await context.GetAccessToken(AuthSettings.Scopes);

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken))
            {
                return;
            }

            await context.PostAsync($"Your access token is: {accessToken}");

            context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
        }

        public virtual async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> item)
        {
            var message = await item;

            if (message.Text == "logon")
            {
                //endpoint v2
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(await context.GetAccessToken(AuthSettings.Scopes)))
                {
                    await context.Forward(new AzureAuthDialog(AuthSettings.Scopes), this.ResumeAfterAuth, message, CancellationToken.None);
                }
                else
                {
                    context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
                }
            }
            else if (message.Text == "echo")
            {
                await context.PostAsync("echo");

                context.Wait(this.MessageReceivedAsync);
            }
            else if (message.Text == "token")
            {
                await TokenSample(context);
            }
            else if (message.Text == "logout")
            {
                await context.Logout();
                context.Wait(this.MessageReceivedAsync);
            }
            else
            {
                context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
            }
        }

        private async Task ResumeAfterAuth(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<string> result)
        {
            var message = await result;

            await context.PostAsync(message);
            context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my MessagesController.cs:

```
namespace Bot
{
    //[BotAuthentication]
    public class MessagesController : ApiController
    {

        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
        {

            if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate)
            {
            }
            else if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
            {

                if (activity.Text.Contains("logon") || activity.Text.Contains("login"))
                {
                    await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new Dialogs.LoginDialog());
                }
                else
                {
                    // Sends user's Id and Name to RootDialog Class
                    StateClient stateClient = activity.GetStateClient();
                    BotData userData = await stateClient.BotState.GetUserDataAsync(activity.ChannelId, activity.From.Id);
                    userData.SetProperty<string>("UserId", activity.From.Id);
                    userData.SetProperty<string>("Name", activity.From.Name);

                    // send these values in the Context
                    await stateClient.BotState.SetUserDataAsync(activity.ChannelId, activity.From.Id, userData);


                    await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new Dialogs.RootDialog());
                }

            }
            else if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Invoke)
            {
               //...

            }
            else
            {
                HandleSystemMessage(activity);
            }
            var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            return response;
        }


    private Activity HandleSystemMessage(Activity activity)
    { 
        //...
    }

}
```

EDIT #1: After setting breakpoints in my code it looks like the error is happening in the WebApiConfig.cs file here:

```
JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings()
{
   ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
                Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented,
                NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
};
```

EDIT #2: The error happens after reaching the line shown in this picture:

[image]

When this line is reached message is null. It immediately leaves this function and goes back to the line:

`await context.Forward(new AzureAuthDialog(AuthSettings.Scopes), this.ResumeAfterAuth, message, CancellationToken.None);`

and then goes back to the JSON lines in WebApiConfig shown in EDIT #1, runs the function `JsonSerializerSettings()` twice and then the exception is thrown.

Here is the Output view of the Exception:

[image]

Comment: have you implemented the `ResumeAfterAuth` method? Can you add the code?

Comment: I added my code. Do I need to do something different in the ResumeAfterAuth since I am using two Dialogs?

Comment: Also, I think the exception is happening at the line `var message = await result;` in ResumeAfterAuth() for some reason?

Comment: Could this have to do with Nuget packages? Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Megan are you still having this problem?  If so what is the last line called before the snippet in your edit?  Is there some JObject that is null? or something that is supposed to be a JObject that is not actually a JObject?  I ask because I have seen this before and that was my problem.

Comment: @JasonSowers Thanks for the help/ Here are the lines above my edit:                                                        `config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;`

Comment: I'm not sure why it would be null...unless the card object that AuthBot's dialog class should return is null?

Comment: I'm not sure either, but if we were sure of everything stack overflow wouldn't exist :) I meant the code executed prior to entering the WebApiConfig Class.  It should be something involving the dialog, and for some reason the dialog is null.  Maybe there is some strange serialization behavior you are missing.

Comment: @JasonSowers Added a secondary edit that details where my code goes before the error is thrown. Thanks

Comment: This has nothing to do with a JObject.  This is something strange as your implementation is close to all the examples I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered the issue. I needed to add these lines under the line `GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);` in my Global.asax.cs file:

```
AuthSettings.Mode = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ActiveDirectory.Mode"];
AuthSettings.EndpointUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ActiveDirectory.EndpointUrl"];
AuthSettings.Tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ActiveDirectory.Tenant"];
AuthSettings.RedirectUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ActiveDirectory.RedirectUrl"];
AuthSettings.ClientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ActiveDirectory.ClientId"];
AuthSettings.ClientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ActiveDirectory.ClientSecret"];
```